# If I commit a new env var to an encrypted secrets file, and the var name is identifiable from the commit message, how much is security reduced?

Tags: encryption

For example, I add

```
SOME_COMMON_API_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

to an encrypted env var file (say with sha-2 family), with the commit message `added key for some common api`.

This means anyone familiar with the framework I'm using knows the secret will be stored in the env var `SOME_COMMON_API_SECRET`.

How much easier is the secrets file now to brute force? Enough to matter? The attacker would also know the length of `xxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: Encrypted or hashed?  You say encrypted and then specify a hashing algorithm.  Unlikely it can be brute forced given that the only way to determine if an API key is correct is by using it - network overhead and ratelimiting would keep you safe at the very least.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, "the only way to determine if an API key is correct is by using it" isn't true. An attacker can only identify there even *is* an API key by successfully decrypting the file. Knowing part of the plaintext makes it easier to recognize a successful decryption. That being said, with a proper encryption algorithm and key material brute-force isn't a viable attack to begin with.